# (Tkinter) Why doesn't itemconfig change the colors of my objects?

Tags: python, tkinter, events, canvas, colors

I am trying to make a code that changes the color of a series of objects, which form a mesh, in the form of a gradient between two colors in a horizontal direction. This change will be made when another object called "ball" is added. I put the objects in an array, and defined a function that iterates this change with `canvas.itemconfig`, however the objects don't change color.

```
import tkinter
import numpy as np

#Sizes
animation_window_width= 12800
animation_window_height= 720
animation_ball_radius = 12.5
    
#Function to put the ball  
def place_ball(event): 
    canvas.unbind("<Motion>")
    plate_animation()
    
#Function to locate the ball 
def locate_ball(event):
    canvas.coords(ball,
        event.x-animation_ball_radius,
        event.y-animation_ball_radius,
        event.x+animation_ball_radius,
        event.y+animation_ball_radius)
    canvas.coords(tball,
        event.x, event.y)

#Function to add the ball
def add_ball():
    canvas.bind('<Motion>', locate_ball)
    canvas.bind('<Button-1>', place_ball)

#Color gradient function
def compute_colors(start, end, limit):
    (r1,g1,b1) = window.winfo_rgb(start)
    (r2,g2,b2) = window.winfo_rgb(end)
    r_ratio = float(r2-r1) / limit
    g_ratio = float(g2-g1) / limit
    b_ratio = float(b2-b1) / limit
    colors = []
    for i in range(limit):
        nr = int(r1 + (r_ratio * i))
        ng = int(g1 + (g_ratio * i))
        nb = int(b1 + (b_ratio * i))
        color = "#%4.4x%4.4x%4.4x" % (nr,ng,nb)
        colors.append(color)

    return colors

#Function to animate the mesh
def plate_animation(): 
    color = compute_colors("red3", "blue", len(plate[0]))
    for o in range(len(plate)):
        for p in range(len(plate[0])):
            canvas.itemconfig(plate[o][p], fill=color[p])
    
    
window = tkinter.Tk()
window.title("Mesh simulation")
window.geometry(f'{animation_window_width}x{animation_window_height}')
canvas = tkinter.Canvas(window)
canvas.configure(bg="black")
canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

plate=np.zeros([12, 17])

for i in range (0, 1250, 78):
    for j in range (0, 690, 62):
        plate[j//62, i//78]=canvas.create_oval(i+5,j+5,i+30,j+30,fill="grey", outline="white", width=2)
        
ball = canvas.create_oval(0,0,0,0,fill="red", outline="white", width=2)
tball = canvas.create_text(0,0, font=("Impact", 8, "bold"), text="Ball")
tkinter.Button(window, text="Add ball", command=add_ball).pack()
window.mainloop()
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Taking advantage, I would also like a way to limit the position that the ball can take so that it can only take that of any of the objects in the mesh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you did not specify the `dtype` for `plate` and it will be float number,
but `canvas.itemconfig()` expects an integer item ID.

Specify an integer `dtype` when you create `plate` to solve the issue:

```py
plate=np.zeros([12, 17], dtype=np.uint32)
```